# Fetching Data from Sql to windows 8.1 app to show

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I have added data into a SQL database through using Windows 8.1 App,
but how can I get the stored data from SQL and show them on my Windows 8 App page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx Sql Data Reader class. Additionally it will need instance of SqlCommand class and configured SqlConnection object.